# Adobe illustrator Script paste

Tags: adobe

I found that command app.paste() but it doesnt return string its just pasting into document text. Basicaly i need command that return clipboard!

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015_3/Illustrator%20JavaScript%20Scripting%20Reference.pdf

http://prntscr.com/cg5qtb

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no command in Illustrator that will return clipboard data. You can use **app.copy()** and **app.paste()** if you want to copy paste between different applications and if you want to use only in Illustrator you can use the **duplicate** method provided in Illustrator documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`app.paste()` causes the new layer it creates to be the only selected layer, so you can access the text contents by returning its `.contents` property like this:

````
#target illustrator

function getClipboard() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var clipboard = '';

    app.paste();
    clipboard = doc.selection[0].contents;
    doc.selection[0].remove();

    return clipboard;
}
function main() {
    alert( getClipboard() );
}
main();```
````